# Printing \x escaped character stored in char array

Tags: c, printing, escaping

I have a software which reads a file and stores it in char* array. There are substrings in it which contain "\xhh" escape character.
That means that the number is stored as "\xhh" string in which 'h' is a digit and every character is separetad. Namely the escape character is not stored as one character.

lets asume that str is a substring from the buffer which contains some escaped string with "\xhh" format. For example the value is for now "\x41".

I want it to be printed as with the escape character "\x".
printing it explicitly results in the string itself:

```
printf(str); //->prints "\x41" and not "A"
```

I've tried printing it with %x:

```
char* tmp = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);    
tmp[0] = '0';
tmp[1] = 'x';
tmp[2] = (char)*(p+1);
tmp[3] = (char)*(p+2);
tmp[4] = '\0'; // Now tmp contains "0x41"
printf("%x",(long)strtol(tmp, NULL, 16)); //->prints 65
printf("\n\x41\n");  //->prints "A"
```

Every conversion I try doesnt bring the 'A' result. How can I print it right?

Comment: Hexadecimal is only a *presentation* issue. Your values are in the end all stored in binary.

Comment: As for *presenting* your value, just print it as hex? Like `printf("\\x%02x", 'A')`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's not constantly 'A', its being read fron file, arranged in array and after some actions has to be print to a file again..

Comment: Well, then `printf("\\x%02x", some_variable_or_array_element)`? Adapt to your use-case.

Comment: but I need to convert it to another representation before, how can I fastly convert "/x41" into 'A' by code for that? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: `\x41` _is_ the character `A`. No need to convert it.

Comment: but its not constly \x41.. Its only an axample for a value. its non const variable, when i try explicitly print it, it prints "\x41" and with "%02x" it prints 65 value()after converting from string to number) .. @PaulOgilvie

Comment: Now you should do something you should have done in the first place, to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And when editing your question include some *specified* input and show the *expected* output of that input, as well as the actual output you get from your MCVE. I find it very hard to understand exactly what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put a character in a string in C that is not normally representable you can put it in as a hexadecimal escaped character, for example:

```
"A string with an \x0d"
```

The compiler replaces the `\x0d` in the string with the hexadecimal character 13, the carriage return. So this is all *compile time*.

To print a/any character as a hexadecimal number use:

```
printf("%x, %x", 0x0d, '\x0d');
```

If you want to precede it with a backslash, you must *escape* the backslash so the compiler won't interpret it:

```
printf("\\x%x", 0x0d);
printf("\n\\x41\n");
```

To print an escaped *character*, you use the `%c` format specifier:

```
printf("%c", (int)strtol(tmp, NULL, 16));
```

Comment: how can I use "\xhh" when the hh digits are a separete non const var?

Comment: Please provide a good example. A variable with the integer value `65` is the same as a character `A`. A digit character `5` has the integer value `53`, which is the integer representation of the ASCII character `5`.

Comment: The issue is that It reads a full file as strings. Than I have for example, from cell 5 to cell 9, a string with "\x41".(and others substrings like it the future). now after proccesing the text I want to print this substring(and others) while interpreting the escape character "\xhh" and not explicitly..

Comment: Have you tried `printf("%c", (int)strtol(tmp, NULL, 16));`?